# how to write bytes to stdout in python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

A test file named == a.py ==

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(0,1000):
        try:
            os.sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"hello\r\n")
            os.sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
        except OSError:
            pass
```

It is ok when it runs alone. But there is problem in following case:

1. Run python a.py | more
2. Press ctrl+c to exit

Then I got Exception OSError: OSError(22, 'Invalid argument') in <_io.TextIOWrapper name='' mode='w' encoding='cp936'> ignored

I have catch the OSError already around the os.sys.stdout.buffer operations, but it still goes wrong.

If i don't use os.sys.stdout.buffer.flush, then there's no error message. If I just use print(), everything is OK.

So how to write bytes to the stdout correctly?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and Python 3.3.0 32 bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`os.fdopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdopen) to reopen stdout with different mode. You can get the file number for stdout with [`sys.stdout.fileno()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.fileno).

Example:

```
>>> fp = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb')
>>> fp.write(b'Hello, world')
12
>>> sys.stdout.mode
'w'
>>> fp.mode
'wb'
>>> fp.flush()
Hello, world>>>
```

Comment: It's interesting to notice that this works fine both for python 2 and 3.

Comment: You should add `closefd=False` if using `os.fdopen()` as a context manager, to avoid it closing the `sys.stderr` file and then not being able to print errors from there onwards in your script.